# Calculating Decay Width of a Photon into a Pair of W Bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model

By studying the Lagrangian of the Standard Model, one can write down the tree level $\gamma WW$ vertex factor as

$iV_{\gamma W^{+} W^{-}}^{\mu \nu \rho}  = i g \big[ (p -q)^{\rho} g^{\mu \nu} +   (q-r)^{\mu} g^{\nu \rho} + (r-p)^{\nu} g^{\rho \mu}  \big]  $

where $g$ is a suitable coupling constant, $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and $r=-p-q$ is the outgoing momentum of the photon.  If I then wish to find the decay width for $\gamma \rightarrow W^{+} W^{-}$, one then writes down the decay amplitude $\mathcal{T}$ and sums $ | \mathcal{T}|^2$ over the outgoing $W$ polarisations.

Are there some standard tricks to carrying this out or some textbook where the calculation is explained in more detail, as I am not sure how to proceed with the computation.

Edit: It has been pointed out that the decay width would vanish but I would still be interested in formally calculating the matrix element squared to see how the calculation goes.

Comment: ... and then you just write down a big $0$ on your page because the decay rate isn't _only_ the matrix element squared... there's also kinematic factors, which will always be zero because there's no way to conserve energy and momentum in this reaction.

Comment: I appreciate that the answer might vanish but I was still interested in how the process would look for the calculation of the matrix element squared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a calculation of such process because the width is identically $0$. One can compute the matrix element as you indicated but a massless photon cannot decay into two massive particles.

This is true even for the more "simple" reaction $\gamma\rightarrow e^+ e^-$, the latter can only happen in an external field like around a nucleus so that energy and momentum can be conserved.

Comment: Since W boson have a width, is there any sneaky way to have the two Ws have different masses such that finite phase space exists?  Probably not.

Comment: @JEB it doesn't matter the masses, a on shell massless particle cannot decay into two massive particles.

Comment: @JEB W boson's "have a width" because they then decay to stable hadrons/electrons and a bunch of neutrinos. So sure you could think of it as a photon decaying to a bunch of stable particles with zero mass uncertainty through a virtual $W$. No there's no "sneaky way"... massless particles are stable and do not decay to massive particles.

Comment: Just a small caveat, in quantum optics ( em in media)  there are massive states called "photons" (https://opg.optica.org/ome/fulltext.cfm?uri=ome-11-8-2722&id=453737 ) . I have had long discussions with optics people.

Comment: In BSM scenarios how are there anomalous $Z Z \gamma $ couplings if they imply a decay which can't happen because of failure to conserve energy-momentum?

Comment: @annav I bet they're never 160 GeV

Comment: @Tom Just because there's a coupling doesn't mean that there's a decay. The photon couples to all charged particles. That doesn't mean it decays to them. I'll say again: "the decay rate isn't only the matrix element squared. there's also kinematic factors". You should look at the decay rate formula in a quantum field theory textbook.

Comment: OK I see your point, I guess the coupling would instead come into play in a scattering since the photon is virtual in that case.  I was still interested in calculating the matrix element squared for practice with the calculations, do you have any tips on how to do that?

Comment: @Tom there is no better way than to compute it yourself or use a tool like Feyncalc. Peskin and Schroeder has a section on computing electroweak amplitudes.

Comment: @CStarAlgebra I started to write down the matrix element by assigning a polarisation $\epsilon^{\mu}$ to each external outgoing boson and multiply with the vertex factor.  Two of these from the W polarisations gets rid of the metric and replaces it with $\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2$, but what happens with the $\rho$ index on $(p-q)^{\rho}$ when the third $\epsilon$ is multiplied in?

Comment: @CStarAlgebra So we look at the first term I get $\mathcal{T} = g ( \epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2) (p-q)^{\rho} \epsilon_3$, where $\epsilon_1 $ and $\epsilon_2$ are the polarizations of the W bosons and $\epsilon_3$ is the polarisation of the photon.  Any hints?